# mvc5 IdentityAuthenticationManager reset database

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

How would I go about resetting the database that backs a `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityAuthenticationManager`.

I went to go add `Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<>);` to global.asax, but what should I use for TContext?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want the DefaultIdentityDbContext if you aren't customizing things:

```
        Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<DefaultIdentityDbContext>());
```